# Run a specific task parallel using Await and Async

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await, telerik-grid

As I was trying to a parallel processing on a particular task where it takes huge time to complete. That is, `ForEach in Linq`. Please consider the below code,

**Code**

```
public async Task<List<int>> ReturnRoutAsync(int UserId, int Id)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(db.RoutingListMembers.Where(a => a.RoutingListId == UserId && a.User.UserDeptId == Id).Select(a => a.UserId.Value).ToList());
}
public async Task<List<int?>> CareAllocCount(List<UserWithDeptId> RouteList)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(RouteList.Where(f => f.PoReceiptId == f.PoReceiptId).Select(f => f.UserId).ToList());
}
public async Task<int> UsersCount(int? UserId)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(db.RoutingListMembers.Where(x => x.RoutingListId == UserId).Select(x => x.UserId).Count());
}

public async Task<List<UserWithDeptId>> GetRoutingList(List<UserWithDeptId> RouteList, int Id)
{
    await RouteList.ForEachAsync(async d => { d.RouteUserIdList = await ReturnRoutAsync(d.UserId.Value, Id); d.CareAllocationCnt = await CareAllocCount(RouteList); d.TotRouteUsers = await UsersCount(d.UserId); });
    return RouteList;
}

public async Task<decimal> ReturnAmount(int Id, int Year)
{
    .... (Some other Logic) ....
    var RouteList = Model.Where(asd => asd.Year == Year).ToList();
    RouteList = await GetRoutingList(RouteList, Id);
    .... (Other logic here)....
    var Amount = NewModelList.Sum(asd => asd.Allocated_Cost_to_Dept); // returns decimal
    return Amount;
}

[GridAction]
public ActionResult _Index(int Year, int? page)
{
      var model = (from Dept in db.UserDepts
                     select new ReviewHead
                     {
                         Header = Dept.Description,
                         DeptId = Dept.Id,
                     }).ToList();
        List<ReviewHead> NewList = new List<ReviewHead>();
        foreach (var temp in model)
        {
            ReviewHead RH = new ReviewHead();

            RH.Amount = ReturnAmount(temp.DeptId, Year); // I am getting the compiler error saying that it cannot convert Task<decimal> to decimal.
            RH.DeptId = temp.DeptId;
            RH.Header = temp.Header;
            NewList.Add(RH);
        }
        return View(new GridModel(NewList));
}

public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T, Task> func)
{
    foreach (var value in list)
    {
        await func(value);
    }
}
```

When I change the above one to use `Task<ActionResult>` like the below code then I am getting server error as the process cannot proceed 'Asynchronously'. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update - I did changed the ActionResult method like below**

```
[GridAction]
public async Task<ActionResult> _Index(int Year, int? page)
{
      var model = (from Dept in db.UserDepts
                     select new ReviewHead
                     {
                         Header = Dept.Description,
                         DeptId = Dept.Id,
                     }).ToList();
        List<ReviewHead> NewList = new List<ReviewHead>();
        foreach (var temp in model)
        {
            ReviewHead RH = new ReviewHead();

            RH.Amount = await ReturnAmount(temp.DeptId, Year);
            RH.DeptId = temp.DeptId;
            RH.Header = temp.Header;
            NewList.Add(RH);
        }
        return View(new GridModel(NewList));
}
```

**Runtime error**

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The asynchronous action method '_Index' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.
Source=System.Web.Mvc
StackTrace:
   at   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at Vibrant.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore() in e:\Vibrant3_SVN_Latest\Vibrant\Vibrant\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 42
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass19.<BeginExecute>b__13()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
InnerException:
```

Comment: See my answer below, notice there is an `await` and a `ToListAsync` that is missing in your code.

Comment: so ``await ReturnAmount`` changes error message or same error?

Comment: My update did compiled fine. but throws runtime exception.

Comment: Can you include the server error (complete stack trace, exception type, and message) you are getting?

Comment: Pl look at my update

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the exception:

> The asynchronous action method '_Index' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously.

It sounds like something can't handle asynchronous code. Normal MVC actions work fine with `async`, so it must be something else. Like this:

> Vibrant.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore() in e:\Vibrant3_SVN_Latest\Vibrant\Vibrant\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 42

Sounds like "Vibrant" - whatever that is - needs to be updated to enable asynchronous requests.

In the meantime, you'll have to make your code synchronous. Which isn't too hard, since the code is actually synchronous already.

In particular, this method:

```
public async Task<List<int>> ReturnRoutAsync(int UserId, int Id)
{
  return await Task.FromResult(db.RoutingListMembers.Where(a => a.RoutingListId == UserId && a.User.UserDeptId == Id).Select(a => a.UserId.Value).ToList());
}
```

has an unnecessary `async`/`await` which is just unwrapping a task and then wrapping the result back in a task, so those can be removed:

```
public Task<List<int>> ReturnRoutAsync(int UserId, int Id)
{
  return Task.FromResult(db.RoutingListMembers.Where(a => a.RoutingListId == UserId && a.User.UserDeptId == Id).Select(a => a.UserId.Value).ToList());
}
```

Furthermore, `Task.FromResult` is a *synchronous* operation. There's nothing asynchronous about this method at all, so we can just make it synchronous. Since it's synchronous anyway, the synchronous representation is more natural:

```
public List<int> ReturnRout(int UserId, int Id)
{
  return db.RoutingListMembers.Where(a => a.RoutingListId == UserId && a.User.UserDeptId == Id).Select(a => a.UserId.Value).ToList();
}
```

After you do that to your methods, your logic is just:

```
public decimal ReturnAmount(int Id, int Year)
{
  .... (Some other Logic) ....
  var RouteList = Model.Where(asd => asd.Year == Year).ToList();
  RouteList = GetRoutingList(RouteList, Id);
  .... (Other logic here)....
  var Amount = NewModelList.Sum(asd => asd.Allocated_Cost_to_Dept); // returns decimal
  return Amount;
}
```

And `_Index` remains the same as your first example.

Comment: Sorries, I am not able to understand your explaination. so, If u could post the whole modified code then it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @DonMax: Sorry, that's not how I roll. What part of my answer isn't clear?

Comment: I do not understand. You want me to change the whole of my code to synchronous way ie, without using `Task, async and await`anywhere??

Comment: @DonMax: It's already synchronous. I'm just recommending you remove the `async`/`await`/`Task`s that don't do anything.